# find the distance between two CG points?

Tags: objective-c, touch, drawrect, uitouch

I am using these methods and these variables

```
CGPoint touchBegan;
CGPoint touchEnd;

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

}

- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

}
```

But I can not get the distance between two points. For example draw a line with your finger and get the distance between a CGPoint touchBegan and CGPoint touchEnd

Any help is appreciated thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't seem to exist any method or function that do this directly, you must take the difference of the two points coordinates and use pythagorean theorem:

```
CGPoint touchBegan;
CGPoint touchEnd;

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch* touch= [touches anyObject];
    touchBegan= [touch locationInView: self.view];
}

- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch* touch= [touches anyObject];
    touchEnd= [touch locationInView: self.view];
    CGFloat dx= touchBegan.x - touchEnd.x;
    CGFloat dy= touchBegan.y - touchEnd.y;
    CGFloat distance= sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
    < Do stuff with distance >
}
```

Comment: I have one last question.

How generate negative numbers?

for example if the slide is from left to right the number is positive

but to generate negative number from right to left 
What I can do?

Comment: @Fabio Distance is always positive. If you wish to determine left vs. right then look at the two `x` values to make your decision. If the `end` value is greater than the `start` value then the user moved to the right.

Comment: Tip: you can use `[touches anyObject]` instead of `[event.allTouches anyObject]`. They are the same.

Comment: `CGFloat distance = hypotf(dx, dy);`

Answer (score 2):

Just implement your own rendition of the [Pythagorean theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem). For example:

```
CGPoint translation = CGPointMake(endPoint.x - startPoint.x, endPoint.y - startPoint.y);
CGFloat distance = sqrtf(translation.x * translation.x + translation.y * translation.y);
```

Or, better, as Rob Mayoff pointed out, use the Math.h `hypotf` method:

```
CGFloat distance = hypotf(translation.x, translation.y);
```